# creating interactive buttons on tkinter which have an effect on storyline

Tags: python, tkinter, button

I am COMPLETELY new to tkinter in python and i am beginning to learn how to code on it. I am creating a storyline where you have to escape a forest (it is a basic story because i want to code instead of coming up with a cool plot)
I have created some buttons for options to make a fire, find food or sleep, but i want to change it slightly so that when you click on whichever button, it gives you different stories for whatever option you choose.

```
print("You are hungry, cold, and sleepy. Do you want to find food, make a fire, or go to sleep. ")
# Create the Tkinter window and set the title
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Random Number Generator")

# Create a button to for the options
fire = tk.Button(window, text="Make a fire")
fire.pack()

food = tk.Button(window, text="Find food")
food.pack()

sleep = tk.Button(window, text = "Go to sleep")
sleep.pack()

# Create a label to display the options
number_label = tk.Label(window, font=("Arial", 48), text="")
number_label.pack()
# Start the Tkinter event loop
window.mainloop()
```

I can click on the buttons fine, how do i make it so that if i click food for example, it will say you found whatever food and so on.
i know this forum is picky on the little details of posts, and i hope my question is detailed enough to understand. Thanks for your help!!

i cant say i didnt try to do something, but i cant wrap my head around what i need.

Comment: Basically the approach I would do is store all your options per step in a dictionary and based on the selected option you can link to the new set up options and refresh the buttons. Either by putting them all in a frame and destroying that frame and rebuilding it each set of questions or if you always have the same number of options you could simply update what each button text is and the commands. That said to keep track of what you are doing each step will likely also need to be stored in some list or dictionary so you can take the appropriate actions down the line for story telling.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're asking?

```
import tkinter as tk
print("You are hungry, cold, and sleepy. Do you want to find food, make a fire, or go to sleep. ")

def showSelection(whichOne):
    if whichOne == 'a':
        number_label.configure(text='You Chose To Make a Fire')
    elif whichOne == 'b':
        number_label.configure(text='You Chose To Find Food')
    else:
        number_label.configure(text='You Chose to Go To Sleep')

# Create the Tkinter window and set the title
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Random Number Generator")

# Create a button to for the options
fire = tk.Button(window, text="Make a fire",command=lambda: showSelection('a'))
fire.pack()

food = tk.Button(window, text="Find food",command=lambda: showSelection('b'))
food.pack()

sleep = tk.Button(window, text = "Go to sleep",command=lambda: showSelection('c'))
sleep.pack()

# Create a label to display the options
number_label = tk.Label(window, font=("Arial", 48), text="")
number_label.pack()
# Start the Tkinter event loop
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! what is lamda?

Comment: @user This link will explain the use of a lambda in a button scenario much better than I can.  If my answer above helped, please uptick it and accept it as the answer.  I can use all the reputation points I can get.  Here's the link: https://coderslegacy.com/python/tkinter-lambda/